# Allowing specific users to only add posts using certain custom taxomy terms

Tags: custom-taxonomy, user-access

I was searching through the forums, but I can only find slightly related issues.

This is my problem:

I'd like to assign some editors the capability to only add posts in a predefined term of a custom taxonomy.

I have made a taxonomy called events, which holds a list with events that are added by an admin. Certain users are only allowed to add posts using a single event, e.g. "Japan" or "Haiti".

Anyone with a hint on how to tackle this? are there user management-plugins that have this kind of capabilities?

Regards,
Joost.

Answer (score 2):

First hook the save_post action: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post

Then check capabilities: You have docs on that right?

Then get_the_terms for the $post_id provided by save_post and the taxonomy you want to check. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms

Then if they are using a term (see note below) they are not allowed to use either stop/delete the post, set a warning, or remove the term.

Note: a taxonomy is a list of terms that can be applied to a post. Example: the taxonomy "Nation" would contain terms like "Mexico", "France", and "India"

Comment: Seems like this would work. But what do you mean by **see note below**? Is that the note in the second URL: `It uses get_object_term_cache() or wp_get_object_terms() to retrieve results`? Is that the term that you refer to in your second to last paragraph?

Comment: The "note below" was at the end of my comment - describing the difference between a taxonomy and a term.

I tried to keep the comment short but can provide any other details needed.

Answer (score 0):

Great article here on [**user roles**](http://www.garyc40.com/2010/04/ultimate-guide-to-roles-and-capabilities/#add-capability) and user role management, for your case maybe look up adding a custom role to each user using WP_User_class or maybe even a new role with same capabilities as editor but + 1 of event_poster or something similar, the article is full of good stuff that you can reference.

Comment: Further more it is possible to register a taxonomy with capability restrictions in place again a link but you may as well read it as is as bits copied and pasted. http://justintadlock.com/archives/2010/06/10/a-refresher-on-custom-taxonomies

Comment: Links are appreciated! There is so much written about access restriction that it is difficult to find the right information.

Comment: Still, I can't find any info on how to restrict access to a specific term within a taxonomy. Restricting access to a taxonomy as a whole is no problem.

Comment: I use [Role Scoper](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/role-scoper/) plugin for this, lets you limit specific terms

Comment: Thanks. I worked with that one in the past, but found it a little difficult to work with. In the end, the customer should be able to easily assign a certain term to a user so that he or she can only post using that term. I will check it out again, though.

Answer (score 0):

Wherever you're displaying the taxonomies for selection by the user when he's logged in (you're assigning caps, so I guess the user should log in), just do a check like this...

```
if(current_user_can('your_custom_capability'))
    { 
      //display only those taxonomies that he should be allowed to post into
    }
```

If you're displaying the default categories/taxonomies list in the dashboard, then you need to look around for a filter that is applied while the categories/taxonomies are listed. I'll check on that filter and see if I can find one.